# Expression for 'for the aforementioned/ stated reasons'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Can someone give me a less formal alternative to the phrase below?

> **for the aforementioned/ stated reasons** (we will satisfy your request).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - Thus
> - Hence
> - Therefore
> - Consequently
> - Accordingly
> - As a result [of]
> - So
> - For this reason

Would all work - pick one that sounds best in context.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases you won't need more than

> Therefore

or even just

> So

Answer (score 2):

> For these reasons,

or

> For the reasons listed,

Answer (score 1):

> **Adv. 1.** ***[hence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hence)*** - (used to introduce a logical conclusion)
> from that fact or reason or as a result; "therefore X must be true"; "the eggs were fresh and hence satisfactory"; "we were young and thence optimistic"; "it is late and thus we must go"; "the witness is biased and so cannot be trusted"
> (syn) *therefore, thus, thence, so*

*Hence, we will satisfy your request.*